# PHP sending post from file to file

Tags: php

Is there any way to post from the first file to the second? I need to use it on an intermediary.
I have tried curl, but I does not work:

```
 $ch = curl_init();  
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://example.com/?cat=nyan");  
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);  
 curl_exec($ch);  
 curl_close($ch);
```

edit: When I directly go to address, it works. I want to use session, how can I do that? I don't want to use post to do it.

Comment: Not very well described problem, but have you considered SESSION

Comment: You realise there's an unclosed quoted string there right?

Comment: @iainn I see a lot of questions with mistakes like that... I wonder how the OP never sees it, or if it is a typo in the question and the OP doesn't realise. It's most peculiar

Comment: When you say it "does not work", what do you mean? Do you get a specific error message? Does it just terminate without doing anything?

Comment: @RobertColumbia only edited to get more upvotes for unblock asking

Comment: That's not the kind of edit that will get you upvotes. You have multiple problems with your question as mentioned in the comments. Handle those and make your question into a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, there are at least 4 ways

- you can use `curl` (as long as you configure it to post),
- `php_cli` via `exec` and run via the command line. (ensure you pass the params properly)
- you can also use `javascript` and `jquery` and use a `$.post` command there
- you could also simply `include` the second file (ensure you pass the params properly)

good luck with your coding :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using session(if you are trying to pass variables )

```
//First file
<?php
     session_start();
     $_SESSION['varname'] = $var_value;
?>

//On the second file
<?php 

    session_start();
    $var_value = $_SESSION['varname']
?>
```

[Check php session basic manuals](http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php)

Comment: as long as you have stored var on Session, it doesn't matter whether you go 2nd file manually or, by the header.